# Redirect to index.html only once

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm very new to php and am working to write a script that will have the url (myurl.com) a user visits redirect to myurl.com/index.html (working with Wordpress & adding a temporary landing page), and from there, you'll be able to access an unrelated link, and then will have the option to continue on to myurl.com and access the Wordpress website like normal. So far, this is what I have.

```
isset($_GET['home'])?$home=1:header("Location:http://myurl.com/index.html");
```

but of course, this is still redirecting when you're on myurl.com after continuing on from the redirect. Any help/advice would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for `home` but not setting `home` thus the loop.

You can pass the `home` variable in with the URL request - let me know if this does not work for your situation:

```
if (!isset($_GET['home'])) {
    header("Location: http://myurl.com/index.html?home=1");
} else {
    // Home is already set dont redirect
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works to redirect, but once you're on myurl.com, clicking on another link within the site applies the redirect again. Any way to get around that?

Comment: Is your entire site loaded through index.html (e.g. `index.html?page=about`) or are you going to another page (e.g. `about.html`) and coming back? Either all references back to index.html have to include the `home` variable or you'll have to re-think what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, and I'm not necessarily sure that I can quickly change all of URLs due to everything being Wordpress dependent. Any ideas to get around this with the existing URLs? Thanks!